# Installing Forum 3.1.12 on EE 2.5.5 - ERROR

Tags: forum

Trying to do an install of the Discussion Forum on EE 2.5.5 and got this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ee() in /(Path Here)/expressionengine/modules/forum/upd.forum.php on line 151

Any ideas? - Forum will not install.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to EE 2.6+ first. The `ee()` function was added in 2.6 so that version of the forum must not be compatible with EE 2.5.5.

Comment: AH - well that stinks!  I guess I am upgrading the site this week!